# Docker-compose reference volumes

Tags: docker-compose, volumes

I need to understand how reference volumes work in docker-compose.

```
...
volumes:
  - ./usr/app
```

In this case, to which host folder will docker link this container folder?

Comment: `/var/lib/docker/volumes`

Comment: Ok. But to which volume? /var/lib/docker/volumes/usr/app?